# Show that $[K:F]=p^2$ and the separability and inseparability degrees of $K/F$ are both equal to p

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let p be prime, $F_p$ be the prime field of p elements, $X$ and $Y$ algebraically independent variables over $F_p$, $K=F_p(X,Y)$, and $F=F_p(X^p-X,Y^p-X)$.

(a) Show that $[K:F]=p^2$ and the separability and inseparability degrees of $K/F$ are both equal to $p$

(b) Show that there exists a field $E$, such that $F\subset E\subset K,$ which is a purely inseparable extension of $F$ of degree $p$.

Can someone tell me how to prove this question? I am a little confused how to analyze this question!

Comment: In line 2, do you mean $Y^p - Y$?

Comment: @Flowers: I suspect that there's no typo. Otherwise the extension would be Galois, and the question would therefore not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Extended hints:

- Show that $X$ is a zero of $m(T)=T^p-T-(X^p-X)\in K[T]$.
- Show that the zeros of $m(T)$ are $X+i,i=0,1,\ldots,p-1$.
- Show that $m(T)$ is irreducible in $K[T]$. If related facts have not been explained in class then you have to work hard at this point. Or search the site with the buzzword Artin-Schreier.
- Show that $F(X)/F$ is Galois and degree $p$.
- Show that $(X-Y)^p\in F$.
- Find $E$.

Comment: Great. I went to bed puzzling over this, and this morning I was prepared to write pretty much the same thing as the above, but of course more long-windedly. I think that by noticing that the fixed field of $\{X\mapsto X-1,Y\mapsto Y\}$ must be of degree $p$ underneath the big field, and clearly contains $x=X^p-X$, you can avoid Artin-Scheier.